# ghostscript unexpectedly returned exit value 1

Tags: ghostscript

Calling ghostscript from a Perl script I get this error:

> "/usr/local/bin/gs" unexpectedly returned exit value 1

In `$!` this string can be found: "Inappropriate ioctl for device" - I am not sure, if this is related to the gs error.

Searching for the documentation of ghostscript, I found this page:

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/API.htm#return_codes

Unfortunatley *1* is not listed there.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

EDIT: After changing the code a bit, I realized that the file given to `gs` was a JPEG and not a PDF. That's probably the reason but does not explain the exit-code of *1*.

For the reference here is the Perl-code which throws the above error message:

```
        my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
            my $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/gs';
            my @args = (qw( -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=- )) ;
            push @args, $tmp_fn;
            use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);
            system($cmd, @args);
        };
        die "ERROR compressing pdf: $stderr" if $stderr;
```

Comment: You're looking at the return codes from some GhostScript API. There's no reason for that to map to `gs` exit codes at all. Look at the man page. And if that doesn't document exit codes, then all you can rely on is zero == success.

Comment: Exit code 1 just means 'fatal error', 0 means success. As Mat says, the API error codes are not the same as the executable's exit code. Ghostscript doesn't support JPEG files as an input, but it will try to interpret whatever input you do give it. If you examined stdout (or run the same command at the shell) you will see what the error is. *don't* rely on any man pages for Ghostscript documentation, use the HTML documentation, the man pages (if even present) are little more than a rough guide.